# Make p5.js canvas responsive for mobile

Tags: mobile, media-queries, responsive, p5.js

I'm having troubles resizing the elements of my p5.js sketch for mobile and big screens.

In particular I'd need the white circle reacting to the sound and the obj to shrink when on mobile and to scale when on big screen. Furthermore, I'd need the info appearing when on hover on the play button to slightly move right - in order for them not to be covered by the button copy, when on mobile.

I tried using Media Queries With JavaScript, but it didn't seem to work.

Here's the sketch's editor:
https://editor.p5js.org/c.b/sketches/yeGBMr1PD

Any thoughts? Thanks!

```js
var song;
var button;
var amp;
var canvas;
var showInfo = false;

let angle;
let extraCanvas;

let kitten;
let train;


function preload() {
  kitten = loadImage('kitten2.jpg');
  train = loadModel('train-corrected.obj');
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas (windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.position (0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '-3');
  song = loadSound('yume.mp3', loaded);
  amp = new p5.Amplitude();
  background('#F4EDED');
  extraCanvas = createGraphics(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  extraCanvas.clear();
}

function loaded() {
  button = createButton('Play');
  button.mousePressed(togglePlaying);
  button.mouseOver(onMouseOver);
  button.mouseOut(onMouseOut);
  button.position(15,15);
  button.style('background-color', '#F4EDED');
  button.style('color:#E21118');
  button.style('font-size', '1.9em');
  button.style('border', '0');
  button.style('background', 'none');
  button.style('outline', 'none');
}

function draw() {
  //sound reaction
  background('#F4EDED');

  var vol = amp.getLevel();
  var diam = map(vol, 0, 0.3, 360, 500);

  fill('#FFFFFF');
  noStroke();
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, diam, diam);
    if(showInfo) {
      let s = 'Yume Miru Kokoro by Riki Miyagawa, \nJapan 1934. \nThis could loop all morning.';
      fill(50);
      text(s, 105, 20, 250, 80); // Text wraps within text box
  }

  // obj

  extraCanvas.ambientLight(30);
  extraCanvas.directionalLight(255, 255, 255, 0, 80, 15);
  extraCanvas.directionalLight(255, 255, 255, 0, -180, 5);
  extraCanvas.directionalLight(86, 54, 2, 0, 0, 1);
  extraCanvas.noStroke();

  extraCanvas.push();

  extraCanvas.rotateZ(frameCount * 0.003);
  extraCanvas.rotateX(frameCount * 0.005);
  extraCanvas.rotateY(frameCount * 0.003);

  // Rotate in direction of mouse
  let posX = width/6;
  let posY = height/6;

  let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY-posY, mouseX-posX);

  // Rotate on MouseDrag
  /*let angle = 0;

  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    angle =  atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
  }*/

  extraCanvas.rotateX(angle);
  extraCanvas.rotateY(angle);
  extraCanvas.rotateZ(angle);

  //extraCanvas.translate(-100, 0, 0);
  extraCanvas.clear();
  extraCanvas.texture(kitten);
  extraCanvas.model(train);

  imageMode(CENTER)
  image(extraCanvas, width / 2, height / 2);
  //image(extraCanvas, 0, 0);
  //extraCanvas.imageMode(CENTER);


  extraCanvas.pop();

}

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 550px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes

function togglePlaying() {
  if (!song.isPlaying()) {
    song.play();
    song.setVolume(0.3);
    button.html('Pause');
  } else {
    song.stop();
    button.html('Play');
  }
}

function onMouseOver() {
  showInfo = true;
}
function onMouseOut(){
  showInfo = false;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey, sorry if I didn't do so. It's just that I don't know how to upload the 3D model in the snippet. That's why I included the p5.js editor

Answer (score 2):

In P5, you have `windowHeight` and `windowWidth` variables by default, so why not use them instead of CSS?

You can use them to check the width of a device in setup, and then use the `windowResized` function to set variables for the size accordingly.

Example:

```
function windowResized() { 
    if(windowWidth < 550) {
        size = 10;
    } else {
        size = 100;
    }
}
```